# xmpp Smack android: Capture stanza users found

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, stanza

I've developed a XMPP Smack Android application and I'm having a problem. When I send a stanza to search new user to open a chat, like that:

```
<iq type="set" to="vjud.myserver.com" id="searchUsers">
    <query  xmlns="jabber:iq:search">
       <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">  
         <field type="text-single" var="nick">  
          <value></value>  
     </field>  
    </x>  
    </query>  
    </iq>
```

Smack log writes this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<iq xml:lang="en" to="server@myserver.com/3462143" from="vjud.myserver.com" 
 type="result" id="searchUsers">  
  <query  
    xmlns="jabber:iq:search">  
    <x  xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="result">  
        <title>Search Results for vjud.myserver.com</title>  
        <reported>  
            <field var="jid" type="text-single" label="Jabber ID" />  
            <field var="fn" type="text-single" label="Full Name" />  
           ...
           <field var="nick" type="text-single" label="Nickname" />  
            ...
            <field var="orgunit" type="text-single" label="Organization 
Unit" />  
        </reported>  
        <item>  
            <field var="jid">  
                <value>user1@myserver.com</value>  
            </field>  
            ...
            <field var="first">  
                <value>test admin 1</value>  
            </field>  
            <field var="middle">  
                <value />  
            </field>  
            <field var="nick">  
                <value>test admin 1</value>  
            </field>  
            ...
        </item>  
        <item>  
            <field var="jid">  
                <value>user2@myserver.com</value>  
            </field>  
            ...
            <field var="first">  
                <value>test admin 1</value>  
            </field>  
            ...
            <field var="nick">  
                <value>test admin 1</value>  
            </field>  
            <field var="bday">  
                <value />  
            </field>  
           ...
            <field var="orgunit">  
                <value />  
            </field>  
        </item>  
    </x>  
  </query>  
</iq>
```

But my Xmpp Smack StanzaListener can't capture it! Can somebody tell me how can I do it to capture it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey can you look this my sample https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio

Comment: Thank you! we well have a look